# How do I plot in Matlab in units of a specified constant?

Tags: matlab

I have to plot a given function where the X-axis must be in terms of a constant a0 from x = 0 to 70*a0 and the Y-axis must be in terms of 1/a0. I have tried using xticks and yticks but the numbers on the x-axis are illegible and since I don't know an upper limit for the y-axis, I cannot define a vector for it. For the y-axis, I only know the spacing between the divisions and not the limits. Is there a way to get the graph in this way?

Here a0 is Bohr's radius and I am trying to plot the radial probability density vs distance.

Comment: If the x-axis values are `x*a0` and the y-axis values are `y/a0`, then plot `y` vs `x`, and put the `a0` and `1/a0` into the axis label (with `xlabel(...)` and `ylabel(...)`). That is, treat the `a0` as part of the units, not part of the values plotted.